# quick/fast integer multiplication in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multiplication, mandelbrot

I am trying to make a quick/efficient Mandelbrot implementation in Ruby. A long long time ago, one way to speed it up was using fixed point integers instead of floats.

So i made the following benchmark, comparing float and integer raising to a square, using multiplication or square ** operand.

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |x|  
  x.report("float-multip") do
    for z in 0..100000 
      zf = z.to_f
      y = zf*zf
    end
  end  

  x.report("float-square") do
    for z in 0..100000 
      zf = z.to_f
      y = zf**2
    end
  end  

  x.report("int-multip") do
    zo = 0
    for zi in 0..100000 
      y2 = zo*zo
      zo += 1
    end
  end   

  x.report("int-multip") do
    for zi in 0..100000 
      y2 = zi**2
    end
  end  
end
```

and this generates the following output:

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
float-multip   0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
float-square   0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
int-multip     0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.250000)
int-multip     0.282000   0.000000   0.282000 (  0.282000)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.782000sec

                   user     system      total        real
float-multip   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.110000)
float-square   0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
int-multip     0.219000   0.016000   0.235000 (  0.235000)
int-multip     0.265000   0.015000   0.280000 (  0.282000)
```

which clearly shows the the Fixnum multiplication is almost twice as slow as floating point.

I have two questions:

- Can anyone explain this? A reason I can imagine is that Fixnum multiplication is slower because of the internal checking whether or not it needs to be converted to a Bignum.
- secondly is there than a quick integer multiplication for ruby?

Comment: Assignment could be slowing you by a few thousandths or hundredths of a second. (IE, the unused scope that has to be monitored and cleaned in the tests, that isn't used like `y`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.8.6 is just slower in this area. 1.8.7 does a little better and 1.9.1 does better still. I couldn't say why but rvm agrees with you and Pavel that 1.8.6 is oddly slow.

```
1.8.6: 
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
float-multip   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.141560)
float-square   0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.146286)
int-multip     0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.223255)
int-multip     0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.183850)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.690000sec

1.8.7:
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
float-multip   0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.092346)
float-square   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.080335)
int-multip     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.068012)
int-multip     0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.081713)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.320000sec

1.9.1:
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
float-multip   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.065532)
float-square   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.081620)
int-multip     0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.065371)
int-multip     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.065761)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.280000sec
```

Comment: Wow great. I have been looking at benchmarks all day. I will try to move to 1.9.1 asap :)

Comment: 1.9.1 is still unstable and has some significant changes to the code. It's the pre-2.0 branch so you may find a lot of interesting differences. I'm not sure if it matters or not for your case but if you're doing production code 1.9.1 may not be the best. Academia on the other hand... :)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things come to mind. You do not specify what Ruby implementation you are using. Since you run Ruby 1.8.6 on Windows, I am going to assume that you are using MRI installed via the Windows One-Click Installer.

This is kind of a worst-case scenario:

1. MRI is the slowest of all the Ruby implementations
2. MRI on Windows is *even slower* than MRI on Linux or OSX
3. The One-Click Installer uses the pre-compiled binaries from Ruby-Lang.Org, which are compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 from 1996, and thus are *even slower* than MRI on Windows compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 or GCC 4.x or even GCC 3.x.

Here's a couple of tips that you could try to improve performance:

- use the [RubyInstaller](http://RubyInstaller.Org/) project, which uses interpreters compiled with GCC 3.x instead of MSVC6,
- maybe recompile the interpreter yourself (it's not that hard with the Rakefiles provided by the [RubyInstaller](https://GitHub.Com/OneClick/RubyInstaller/) project) with GCC 4.x and/or different optimization options (RubyInstaller is compiled with moderate optimization options and for generic 386 CPUs),
- use a newer version of MRI than 1.8.6,
- use a different implementation of Ruby:

  - YARV is significantly faster than MRI (unfortunately, it only implements Ruby 1.9, so you might have to change your code),
  - [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) is significantly faster than YARV in a lot of scenarios, and it implements both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9 (it also has a `-fast` commandline option, which is slightly incompatible with Ruby, but improves performance, including arithmetic performance) and
  - [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/) might also be faster than YARV, depending on the workload.

In the latter two cases you might want to revise your benchmarks a bit. Both eventually can compile Ruby code to native machine code, but it might take a while. JRuby for example compiles to JVM bytecode after a method has been executed 20 times and HotSpot Server compiles JVM bytecode to native machine code after it has executed 20000 times. Also, compilation itself takes time, so the program needs to run a while to gain back that cost through improved performance.

In particular, Charles Oliver Nutter, one of the JRuby lead developers, said that depending on the workload, JRuby might take up to 5-15 seconds to ramp up to full speed. Your benchmarks are about 100x too fast (here's a sentence you don't hear every day ...).

Comment: Yeah, i also read in this post: http://antoniocangiano.com/2009/08/10/how-much-faster-is-ruby-on-linux/ that ruby on linux is also substantially faster (70% for ruby 1.9.1 and 100% for ruby 1.8.6). So what i am going to try to do is move all my code to 1.9.1, hope most of my gems/plugins are compatible. There is two compatibilities to worry about: ruby 1.9.1 on the one hand, and the other binary platform from the ruby installer. But i think it will be well worth the effort. On the other hand i will test it on linux in a virtual box on my machine, and maybe that'll be even quicker ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain your tables.  But I can explain mine (ruby 1.8.7):

```
                   user     system      total        real
float-multip   0.600000   0.000000   0.600000 (  0.612311)
float-square   0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.649399)
int-multip     0.450000   0.010000   0.460000 (  0.457004)
int-multip     0.690000   0.000000   0.690000 (  0.692879)
```

Whoops.  Integer multiplication beats floating point ones.

Since your processor is 5 times slower than mine (I increased the number of repeats in your benchmark in ten times), there must be something not ruby-concerned.

`**` operation probably used floating-point arithmetic(exp(x*ln(2)), so it is as slow as other floating-point operations.

Comment: Concerning :) I am running ruby 1.8.6 on Windows, so maybe that explains things. Going to try in Virtual Box :)

Comment: Indeed, slower integer square is kinda catches eye. For JRuby integer square is actually slower than float squares.

Answer (score 0):

jruby may have quicker arithmetic (or 1.9.x) also doing it in C (ex: http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/inline_optimization.html ) would help speeds obviously